# Deployment with Heroku and React/Rails with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, heroku, webpack

I am currently working on an app that uses react as front-end and rails as back-end, all of this using webpack. I have decided to deploy my app using Heroku, but I came to some troubles. My production front-end is awful, but my backend API works just fine (the requests in the production are made correctly.). The app runs correctly locally.

This is the link from my Heroku app: https://andrei-tocu-jogging-app.herokuapp.com/

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jogging-app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "ajax-request": "^1.2.3",
    "antd": "^4.11.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "1.22.4"
  }
}
```

I have also tried to run these commands to install the dependencies:

```
heroku run bundle install

heroku run yarn install
```

Is there a proper configuration to deploy the application when using react webpack?

Comment: How are you handling the CSS for the react part? your application.css is empty and you said you are handling all the react code with webpacker, maybe you are missing a `stylesheet_pack_tag :application` in your head along with the `javascript_pack_tag :application` you should already have (or maybe `stylesheet_pack_tag :index` since that the name of your react entry point)

Comment: In my application.html.erb layout, I only have the <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>,  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>, <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %> tags and in the javascript folder I only have a custom.css file and not much css in it, because I use ant design for the front-end.

Comment: For some reason your assets/css/application.css is empty. If you have a `custom.css` file in your webpacker folder you need to link that too. how are you using that ant design framework? you should show your css related files